# Cannot find store in redux connect in a Jest Test

Tags: redux, jestjs

I am getting the following error while trying to setup a component in my jest test :

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(TestComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(TestComponent)".

My test looks like this :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { Map } from 'immutable';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import TestComponent from '../TestComponent ';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

describe('test ', () => {
  test(' testing', () => {
    const state = { blah: 1 };
    const reducer = s => s; //dummy reducer

    const store = createStore(reducer, state);

    const component = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TestComponent />
      </Provider>
    );

    const wrapper = shallow(component);
    let json = wrapper.html();
    expect(json).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

and the component being tested looks like this :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TestComponent extends Component {
  render = () => {};
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { blah: state };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(TestComponent);
```

I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with this. It all looks kosher to me. When calling `html()` it cannot find the store.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your wrapper component a function instead of variable:

```
export const testWrapper = Component => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {Component}
    </Provider>
  );
};

const wrapper = shallow(testWrapper(<TestComponent/>));
    let json = wrapper.html();
    expect(json).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Also I'd recommend looking into [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you need to create mocked `store` and pass it to the component wrapped by `connect` function.

`index.ts`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

interface ITestComponentProps {
  blah: any;
  store: any;
}

export class TestComponent extends Component<ITestComponentProps> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  public render() {
    return <div>{this.props.blah}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { blah: state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestComponent);
```

Unit test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ConnectedTestComponent, { TestComponent } from './';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const state = 1;
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore(state);

describe('test', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    const connetedTestComponentWrapper = shallow(<ConnectedTestComponent store={store} />);
    const testComponentWrapper = connetedTestComponentWrapper.find(TestComponent);
    expect(testComponentWrapper.prop('blah')).toBe(state);
    expect(testComponentWrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57290601/index.spec.tsx
  test
    ✓ t1 (54ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        3.089s, estimated 5s
```

snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`test t1 1`] = `"<div>1</div>"`;
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57290601